# Trying to create a line chart for multiple Vendors/Products

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a worksheet that looks like this:

[image: Sample of data (more dates and vendors not pictured)]

This is just a sample. The full sheet includes multiple dates and vendors. On a separate sheet I am trying to create a line chart with the following features:

1. x-axis from `Date` column
2. y-axis from `Price` column
3. Results filtered by `Product` column. A drop down menu allows user to select the `Product` he wants to track.
4. Multiple lines (color coded with legend) for each `Vendor` with pricing data for the selected `Product`

As an example, see below. With the exception of a filter to select different products, this is basically what I am going for.

[image: Example of what I am after]

I have tried inserting a chart in multiple different ways, using recommendations, creating from scratch, etc. I have failed in all my attempts so far to build this out.

Comment: Autofilter on the vendors and make sure the chart is set to ignore hidden rows (right click on chart -> Select data -> hidden and empty cells)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad do I need to pivot so that each vendor is it's own column? I am used to using Tableau where keeping vendors together in one column works.

Comment: No need to a pivot table, just a filter (Data -> Filter)

Comment: Filtering will only get you one series in the chart. Make a pivot table with dates in the left column, products across the top, and prices in the values area. Filter to get the products you're interested in. Then insert your line chart.

Comment: You can create a Pivot Chart and group the Date in PivotTale.